# Prompt user for input from application started via Process.start()

Tags: c#, process.start, redirectstandardoutput

I am currently creating a console application to interact with git. This works fine with redirecting the output of my command to the console application but now some commands prompt for inputs like `PassPhrase` or `y/n for owerwrite`. How to redirect these prompts and ask for inputs from the user.

```
var process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workDir;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = appName;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                process.Start();
                var output = new List<string>();
                
                while (process.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    output.Add(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                }

                while (process.StandardError.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    output.Add(process.StandardError.ReadLine());
                }
                process.WaitForExit();
                foreach (var opt in output)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(opt);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read output and error asynchronously; this will both make it possible for you to read input from the user in the meantime, and avoid a hang when the buffer for standard error gets full (you're only reading it after standard output ends, which is not enough).

Processes don't *ask* for input; they just read the input stream (when using *standard* input, of course). The simplest way to take care of this is to keep reading standard input on your side, and posting the received data to the standard input of your "hosted" process.